# Change Clock Dial Image

Tags: java, android, eclipse, widget, settings

I am creating an Analog Clock Widget for learning purposes and would like to know how I can make a settings layout to change the clock dial image. I have the widget done already but I can't seem to get an onclicklstener to bring up the settings layout.

This is what I have:

```
@Override
public void onDeleted(Context  context, int[] appWidgetIds) 
{super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context  context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action))
    {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        Intent AlarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.alarmclock.AlarmClock"));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, AlarmClockIntent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, pendingIntent);

        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);
    }
}
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int[] appWidgetIds) 
{
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.settings);
        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(context,Widget.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, launchActivity, 0);
        updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, pendingIntent);
        ComponentName myComponentName = new ComponentName(context, Settings.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myComponentName, updateViews);
}

}
```

Comment: "dont know where to start" will always get you downvotes, you need to give us more to work with than that.

Comment: I have updated the OP with more info

Comment: Yes, and I've removed my downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked again [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945402/settings-activity-not-launching/12945420#12945420).

For future visitors:

Put the code that makes sure the `PendingIntent` is set, in the `onUpdate()` method. This makes sure that as soon as the widget is put on the homescreen that the `PendingIntent` is set.

So:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgets) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_activity);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Info.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Widget, pendingIntent);
```

Also:

If you would also like to have the info `Activity` pop up automatically when first adding the widget to the home screen, you should read [this userful piece of information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring).